# Drawing Scale Image from rectangle

Tags: visual-studio-2010, graphics, c++-cli, buffer, picturebox

I am writing a delivery program for my final exam for my college on c++. I've downloaded a hd googlemaps screenshot but I have a big problem to draw it on my panel. I create a rectangle as a zoom, to draw just that portion of the image. But my code doesn't seem to be doing that. I need to draw the rectangle on my panel as a scale image of the real picture, cause I will be doing zoom, and moving the map as google maps, so I need to control the size of the rectangle. When I run this code, it just shows half of the image.

```
anchoImagen = PB_Mapa->Width/zoom; // zoom=1
altoImagen =  PB_Mapa->Height/zoom; 
Graphics ^g = this->P_Mapa->CreateGraphics();

int gWidth = (int)g->VisibleClipBounds.Width;
int gHeight = (int)g->VisibleClipBounds.Height;
BufferedGraphicsContext ^espacioBuffer = BufferedGraphicsManager::Current;

// Colocamos el tamaño máximo del Buffer 
// el +1 es para evitar errores de memoria.
espacioBuffer->MaximumBuffer = System::Drawing::Size( gWidth + 1, gHeight + 1 );

// Creamos un canvas dentro del espacio del buffer utilizando el canvas
// del formulario
BufferedGraphics ^buffer = espacioBuffer->Allocate(g, Drawing::Rectangle(0, 0, gWidth, gHeight));
buffer->Graphics->Clear(Color::White); 

// Declaramos un rectangulo con las dimensiones del pedazo del sprite a utilizar
Bitmap^ imgTransparente = gcnew Bitmap( PB_Mapa->Image);
Drawing::Rectangle porcionAUsar = Drawing::Rectangle(x,y,anchoImagen,altoImagen);

// Dibujamos la imagen en la posicion 
buffer->Graphics->DrawImage(imgTransparente, 0,0, porcionAUsar, GraphicsUnit::Pixel);

buffer->Render(g);

// Limpiamos la memoria reservada
delete buffer;
delete espacioBuffer;
delete g;
```

Comment: Anyone know what language that is? Is it c++-cli?

Comment: Its developed on Visual Studio 2010 c++-cli